# How to calculate conversion rate of names (strings) appearing in multiple rows with a column stating TRUE or FASLE for a conversion on each row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query that will calculate the conversion rate associated with each name in a table such as the one below (assume the real table has thousands of different names)

| Name | Converted |
| --- | --- |
| abc | TRUE |
| abc | FALSE |
| xyz | FALSE |
| dhk | TRUE |
| dhk | TRUE |
| dhk | TRUE |
| dhk | FALSE |

Since abc has one true and one false the query should display a conversion rate of 50% (1 TRUE / 2 Total = 50%). For dhk the conversion rate would be 75% (3 TRUEs/ 4 Total), and for xyz it would be 0% since there are no TRUEs.

The final output of the query should look like the following:

| Name | Conversion Rate |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 50% |
| xyz | 0% |
| dhk | 75% |

OR if I could figure out how to get the output below that would also be enough for me to figure out the rest

| Name | Converted | Conversion Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | TRUE | 50% |
| abc | FALSE | 50% |
| xyz | FALSE | 0% |
| dhk | TRUE | 75% |
| dhk | TRUE | 75% |
| dhk | TRUE | 75% |
| dhk | FALSE | 75% |

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select name, 
  avg(if(converted, 100, 0)) ConversionRate
from your_table
group by name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

or, you can use below

```
select *, 
  avg(if(converted, 100, 0)) over(partition by name) ConversionRate
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Comment: When I run this on my table it only outputs 0, 50, or 100. I checked some names that have a 40% conversion rate and it just rounds up to 50%. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: just tested for described scenario and see no problem! 40% shown as a 40%. you should better troubleshoot your case

Comment: It worked I found my issue, thank you

Comment: great! just curious - what was the issue?

Comment: I had an additional count column that I temporarily added and interfered

Answer (score 1):

This is an intuitive solution, using the traditional conversion rate formula:

```
SELECT Name, 
  COUNTIF(Converted)/COUNT(1) ConversionRate
FROM conversion_table
GROUP BY Name
```